# Emacs: Define macro in comment and automatically execute it

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

I'm using Emacs/AucTeX for editing LaTeX files. In some of my LaTeX files, I have defined some "file-specific" command (e.g. `\todo{...}` in one file, `\compute{...}` in another, and so on), so I can keep track of what open problems I have in my documents.

The Emacs command `highlight-regexp` does quite a good joob in highlightning all occurences of `\todo{...}`s resp. `\compute{...}`s. But up to now I have to execute the highlightning manually every time I open the corresponding file.

Is there a way of telling Emacs/AucTeX to invoke specific commands when opening a particular file? I would like to define these commands *inside* the corresponding file, so I can easily adjust it for different files (maybe included in local variables).

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "master"
%%%
%%% here I would like to have something like:
%%% execute highlight-regexp for specific arguments
%%%
%%% End:
```

Comment: you know about the todonotes package? it is excellent.

Comment: Thank's for the hint. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% eval: (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\\\todo" (0 font-lock-warning-face))))
%%% End:
```

See [Section 57.3.4.1, Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), for more details.

Comment: I must admit I do not really know how this works, but it does work indeed. I read the manual had the thought to do it with `eval`, but I wasnt able to figure out, how it actually works.

However, I read that one shall not include stylistic formatting hints into local variables, but rather into the personal `.emacs`. Nonetheless, it answers the question, so accepted.

Comment: You could avoid the lambda by using a hook,  (add-hook 'tex-mode-hook '(lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords nil
'(("\\\\todo" (0 font-lock-warning-face))))))

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hook in combination to local vars.  For example,  you could add a local variable `dohighlight` or something and then write a function like this:

```
(defun condhighl ()
 (when (boundp 'dohighlight)
 (highlight-regexp "regexp")))
```

and then add that function as a hook for AucTex

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'condhighl)
```

You can then add the dohighlight var in your local vars to buffers you want to highlight the code in.

Comment: That's a nice, elegant solution.

I do wonder if there's a minor mode for just what he describes, though...

Comment: The solution is elegant. But it seems that Emacs does first switch to `tex-mode` (i.e. executing all hook-stuff) and *after* that, loading the file. That means, it seems that the variable is `void` at the critical point of time.

Comment: It looks like text-mode squashes local vars.  I can get this to work in other modes using other mode hooks.

Comment: Yepp, looks so. When I try to get the variable's contents via `describe-variable`, I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

After using `highlight-regexp` to set up your highlighting, `hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns` (M-s h w) will write the patterns into the buffer as a magic comment.

You probably want to add a `mode: hi-lock` after the `mode: latex` line too, to activate the highlighting as soon as you open the file.